# values not read from array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine

This is my first time using a 2D array and i cant seem to get a fix for this. i am working in unity and i have a button for each of the methods at the bottom of the codes. every time i press a button the debug shows that the method is called correctly and even adds it to the previously stored value correctly.

the problem is when i try to assign something to a value stored in the array it doesn't retrieve the right value. so in this case if i call `add addenergy();` 2 times the debug would show

> "added 1 to 0,02"

even though i set it to 3 in start. the checking value would still be 3 and tab would also show 3. what am i doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class factioncontroller : MonoBehaviour {

public int[,] skills = new int[4, 3];

public int check;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

 skills[0, 0]=3;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("tab")) { Debug.Log(skills[0, 0]);         
    check = skills[0, 0];
}
public void addskill(int x, int y) { skills[x, y] += 1; Debug.Log("added 1    to" + x + "," + y + skills[x, y]); }
public void addenergy() { addskill(0,0); }
public void addregen() { addskill(0, 1); }
public void addmovement() { addskill(0, 2); }
public void addusesS() { addskill(1, 0); }
public void addduration() { addskill(1, 1); }
public void addemp() { addskill(1, 2); }
public void addrangeD() { addskill(2, 0); }
public void adddistract() { addskill(2, 1); }
public void addstun() { addskill(2, 2); }
public void addrangeG() { addskill(3, 0); }
public void addusesG() { addskill(3, 1); }
public void addmobi() { addskill(3, 2); }
}
```

Comment: You are saying that you call `stun()` which calls `addskill(2, 2)` but the output you are talking about `added 1 to 0,02` corresponds to `addSkill(0, 0)`.

Comment: I see you've edited the question and you are calling `addenergy()` two times instead of `addstun()`. `skills[0, 0]` equals `2` according to your output so what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that the debug after the method ouputs 2 while the debug on tab outputs 3. but they should both output 5. because 3 was set and 2 was added

Comment: And where, when and in what order are you calling `Start()` and `addenergy()`? Obviously the order they are running in is not the order you are explecting. Figure that out first.

Comment: Are you sure `Start` ever gets called? If it gets called after `addenergy` it would reset skills to 3.

Comment: in unity start is called once in the beginning and update gets called after that continuously.

Comment: Put a `Debug.Log` in `Start` to confirm this.

Comment: its my first time using a 2d array but i have been coding c# on unity for a year now so im pretty sure start gets called once. not to sound mean ive just been stuck on this for 6+ hours now and not getting usefull answers anywhere

Comment: @ace *Pretty sure* isn't helpful. Either you are sure or not, why not set a breakpoint on all three methods and see in which order (and how many times) they are called?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the order in which you are calling the methods, but if your intention is to initialize `skills`, then why not initializing it in a constructor?

Remove the `Start()` method, and add the following one:

```
// Use this for initialization
public factioncontroller()
{
    skills[0, 0] = 3;
}
```

This will be **guaranteed** to be called before you call ***any*** instance method on this class.

From what you are experiencing, it seems that `Start()` is not being called at all, or called **after** `addenergy()`

Comment: maybe im bad at explaining :/. the problem is not the initialization but incrementing the values somehow stores 2 different ones. the debug on the methods reads an incremented value which works correctly when called multiple times but whenever i try to read the value from somewhere else it reads the 3

Comment: @ace *What is the order of execution of the three methods*? (Not what you think it is, but the *real* order of execution, that is, set a breakpoint and step through it)

Comment: there is no particular order because they are called depending on which button is pressed and each accesses a different index on the array so they shouldn't interfear with each other

Comment: @ace Guessing is not allowed on programming. Confirm it and be sure.

Comment: i already did this. its why the debug also shows which value is accessed